# Get PDF file from raw data in java

Tags: java, parsing, pdf

I have a server that returns me some raw pdf data.

This is an example of the data: `%PDF-1.7\n%äãÏÒ\n9 0 obj\n<</Length 8 0 R/Filter/FlateDecode/N 3/Range[0 1 0 1 0 1 ]>>\nstream\nx…`

I've never had worked with this, so my first idea was this:

```
File file = File.createTempFile("File", ".pdf");
try (               
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream())
    {
        baos.write(bytes);
        baos.writeTo(fos);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        log.error(e.getMessage());
    }
```

The problem is that the result is a corrupt pdf file that, when opened with some plain text editor, it only shows hexadecimal data.

How can I print this so it's shown correctly?

Comment: Can you show us full data of this pdf file? @Slifer Dragon

Comment: I can't do that because it could contain confidential data